# Flow type of React's ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

What type returns `React.createRef()`?

I have tried `React.Ref<HTMLSelectElement>`, `React$Ref<HTMLSelectElement>`, `React$Ref<typeof HTMLSelectElement>` and a few more, but nothing works. It is either missing, or wrong type.

Does Flow even support refs created via `createRef`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by the [definition of `React.createRef`](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/f853c93b3aeadfca5c52ca21ccddc86a3fb7e6bc/lib/react.js#L231-L232), you should be able to do something like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<{}> {
  ref: { current: null | HTMLDivElement };

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.ref = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    return <input ref={this.ref} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: So there is no prepared type available?

Comment: @menfon Not to my knowledge.